# PHP method callback

Tags: php, callback, closures

How to pass method callback as a parameter to another method? All the examples I've seen use functions, but not methods. What I've tried is:

```
call_user_func($this, 'method_name', [$param1, $param2,...]);
```

Also is there another, more elegant way, like just passing `$this->method_name` as a parameter?

I know I could add the callback as:

```
function () use ($param1, $param2,...) {
  return $this->method_name($param1, $param2);
}
```

But I would like to omit the closure part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use `[$obj, 'method']` as an callback, bind to an object.

```
class A { 

    public $b = 'test'; 

    public function callback() { 
        echo $this->b; 
    } 
} 

$a = new A();
$f = [$a, 'callback'];
$f();
```

Comment: I have a private constructor with arguments, so I can't make an instance by calling default constructor. Also, I'm calling this callback inside of the same class, so could the instance initialization be replaced with $this or something?

Comment: Tested it: yes, you can use $this.